# when clicking learn more in dropbox website ? how the page slide to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want this effect in my website https://www.dropbox.com/

when clicking in learn more the page slide down to the lower portion how to do this? please help

Comment: `cool`, show us what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
     {
     $('#gototop').click(function(){
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
      return false;
     }
     );
     $('#gotobottom').click(function()
     {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
      return false;
     }
     );
     }
    );
    </script>`

Refer:

[Jquery Slide from Top to Bottom](http://www.macsaveny.com/code/jquery-slide-top-and-bottom-page)

For Demo:

CLick on "Drop me A Line"/"Slide Back to Top"

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

you can try this jQuery for your anchor

```
var offsetTop;
$('.selector').click(function (e) {
    try {
        var href = $(this).attr("href"),
                offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top + 1;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: offsetTop
        }, 800);
    } catch (err) { }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
when you click on learn more(with class learn ) ,scroll goes to bottom (#learndiv)

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
      $(".learn").on("click" ,function()
        {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#learndiv').offset().top});        
        });

});  

</script>

<p><a  class='learn'>learn more</a></p>



<div id="learndiv">
hello this is lear more div 

</div>
```

Comment: Ok fine but how to adjust the height of page which contains learn more in such a way so that we see only the first slide by default and when we click on learn more we see the slide.??? :) @Mr7

Comment: right now i m in office.actually your website(https://www.dropbox.com/) is blocked in our company.i can't see.i just gave answer by reading your question.                        Regarding height issue:ok ,you want to scroll to first slide.......can you tell me that there are how many slide in bottom ?

Comment: will it make a difference? i mean i just want my first slide to attain the full height by default.... @Mr7 :) :)

Comment: you can give height  to first silde dynamically with jquery by adding          $('firstslide').addClass('newcss');                    .newcss{height:00px;}